# How to show form before sleep?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm using `System::Drawing::Graphics` at Windows Forms. I want do draw some stuff, then wait for two seconds, clear it and then draw another stuff. But if I do it like this

```
System::Void MyForm_Load(...) {
    // first drawing
    System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(2000);
    // second drawing
}
```

I don't see the form for two seconds and then it appears with the second drawing. How to show the form after the first one, before starting sleeping?

Comment: If I described the problem unclear please let me know, I'll edit question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sleep locks the load event. So the form can't be displayed.
Look for a timer and use the tick-event of the timer to change the stuff you wants to draw.